# "тут" і "тутА" - різниця

Tags: граматика

Я зазвичай використовую слово **"тут"**, але інколи чую **"тутА"**.
Якщо цей варіант (тут**А**) не помилка, тоді яка різниця у використанні даних слів?

Answer (score 2):

Згідно з [СУМом](http://sum.in.ua/s/tuta) єдина відмінність це розмовність варіанта *тута*:

> **ТУ́ТА**, *присл., розм.* Те саме, що [тут](http://sum.in.ua/s/tut) 1. — *Ой піду я в гай зелений, Посажу я руту. Якщо зійде моя рута, Остануся тута* (Тарас
> Шевченко, II, 1963, 176); [Дядько Лев:] *Лукашу, де ти? гов!* [Лукаш
> (озивається з верби):] *Я тута, дядьку!* (Леся Українка, III, 1952,
> 220).
> **Тута ж** — у цьому самому місці. *За столом сидить
> Кармелюк і його гості, селяни.. Тута ж кілька душ гайдамаків* (Степан
> Васильченко, III, 1960, 180).